# How to use laravel route with parameter in external JS file

Tags: jquery, laravel, routes

I have an external js file .js and I want to use the following url which fetches me the json data to be used in the datatable.

`https://url/admin/farmers/products-data/1` I fetch the json using the url parameter. I just don't know how to add it to the js file.

```
var dt_project = dt_project_table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
        'url':"https://url.com/admin/farmers/products-data/{parameter}",
         dataSrc: 'products'
    },  // JSON file to add data
    ordering: false,
    columns: [
        // columns according to JSON
        { data: '' },
        { data: 'title' },
        { data: 'description' },
        { data: 'code' },
        { data: 'delivery_mode' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Is your your issue figuring out how to pass `1` to `ajax` ?

Comment: Yes please. I want to pass 1 to ajax through the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the parameter in a `data-` attribute of an element on the page and then retrieve it with jQuery in the external js file. Try this

Do something like this in the HTML

```
<div id="some-element" data-id="1">
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

And this in the external js file

```
var parameter = $('#some-element').data('id');
var dt_project = dt_project_table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
        'url':"https://url.com/admin/farmers/products-data/"+parameter,
         dataSrc: 'products'
    },  // JSON file to add data
    ordering: false,
    columns: [
        // columns according to JSON
        { data: '' },
        { data: 'title' },
        { data: 'description' },
        { data: 'code' },
        { data: 'delivery_mode' }
    ] 
});
```